# Count number of relations between 2 variables

Tags: r, count

Recently, I wanted to count the number of occurence of a relationship between 2 variables whatever the order of the relation is. In other words,

```
Variable1 Variable2
A          B
B          A
```

I should get

```
Variable1 Variable2 Weight 
A          B        2
```

I could tried something like

```
result <- aggregate(var_to_sum, by=list(var1,var2), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

However I dont know how to make A B equals to B A

```
Author1 <- ifelse(var1>var2,var1,var2)
```

But it does not work, any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The stata code is not useful. Instead, describe what you want to do and add some example data. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162) for more information on how to do that in a good way.

Comment: Sorry for that. Imagine that I have two variables var1 and var2, i want to count the number of relationships between var1 and var2. So in my example if var1 equals A and then B and var2=B and then A so i should only have one relationship with A B and a weight of 2

Comment: I understand that. But you should add example data to your question that potential answerers can work with.

Comment: I tried to edit my question

Comment: Can you sort the rows by any chance? If yes, I have an idea using plyr's count function. By sorting rows, make sure that A always comes before I, B comes before C, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not provide any sample data, I'll use this data set:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(var1 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 30, replace = TRUE),
                   var2 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 30, replace = TRUE),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`data` is a data frame with two columns and all entries are "A", "B", "C", or "D".

First, I create a column that contains both variables in standard order and then count:

```
data <- transform(data, comb = ifelse(var1 < var2,
                                      paste(var1, var2, sep = ":"),
                                      paste(var2, var1, sep = ":")))
counts <- as.data.frame(table(data$comb))
counts
##   Var1 Freq
## 1  A:A    3
## 2  A:B    3
## 3  A:C    2
## 4  A:D    4
## 5  B:B    4
## 6  B:C    4
## 7  C:C    3
## 8  C:D    6
## 9  D:D    1
```

If you want to have an extra column for each of the variables again, you could for instance use the function `separate()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
counts_split <- tidyr::separate(counts, Var1, c("var1", "var2"), sep = ":")
counts_split
##   var1 var2 Freq
## 1    A    A    3
## 2    A    B    3
## 3    A    C    2
## 4    A    D    4
## 5    B    B    4
## 6    B    C    4
## 7    C    C    3
## 8    C    D    6
## 9    D    D    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Sorry my question was not very clear. But the way you described and explained me is great. I wish you a nice evening

Comment: @branchwarren What your question lacked was some exampke data as I provide in the first code snippet of my answer.

Comment: I will take your response as an example for my future questions

Comment: Sick answer,  nice usage of the transform function

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  For values in "V1" that is greater than "V2", we assign "V2" as "V1" and viceversa.  Grouped by "V1" and "V2", we get the nrow (`.N`) i.e. "weight".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[V1>V2, c("V2", "V1") := list(V1, V2)][, 
                            .(weight=.N) ,.(V1, V2)]
#   V1 V2 weight
#1:  A  B      2
#2:  C  D      2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
              V2=c("B", "A", "D", "C"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach. You can use the `pmin` and `pmax` functions.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                  V2=c("B", "A", "D", "C"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% transmute(V1n=pmin(V1, V2), V2n=pmax(V1, V2)) %>% 
  group_by(V1n, V2n) %>% summarise(weight=n())
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: V1n [?]
# 
#     V1n   V2n weight
#   (chr) (chr)  (int)
# 1     A     B      2
# 2     C     D      2
```

Comment: @ Ven Yao Thanks a lot!